# considarations for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS dual boot with Passthrough and standar boot

Tags: dual-boot, nouveau, clone, gpu-driver

I running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with nouveau drivers and the integrate graphics card, and a dedicate nvidia gpu for a KVM GPU passthrough configuration. All works perfect. However, I am planing go back to use standar Ubuntu configuration without gpu passthrough, in order to use the gpu inside Ubuntu with nvidia drivers.
Should I clone all the Ubuntu system or just duplicate kernel and place a new entry in the grub menu?

Comment: Since there is no Ubuntu 20 what are you running? 20.04 or 20.10?

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  There is no such release. Ubuntu uses *yy.mm* format (year.month of release) for all server & desktop releases, the *yy* being used only for IoT and specialist appliance/device releases (also suitable for cloud use) that can use *snap* packages only.  By Ubuntu 20 do you mean Ubuntu Core 20?  as it's a different product to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (desktop or server).

Comment: Yes, It is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, thanks for the clarification. Is there an important difference in this type of configuration in the 20.XX versions?

Comment: What he said, there is 20.10, however as 21.04 is out, you should prefer this. But 20.04 is fine :-)

Comment: @txirrindulari : 20.04 is the latest LTS version till now ( LTS should be more stable and supported for several years => see [release-cycle](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle) and [releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) )

Comment: Despite of the Ubuntu version, Could you offer me some light on the question of configuration? Thank you all @gilles-gaido

Comment: I'm sorry to not answer : I have neither experience nor skills on this topic : I discovered this technique today with your question. Maybe these step-by-step videos will provide you some hints about the configurations :   
[Easiest GPU passthrough guide for Ubuntu 20.04](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ID3dlVHDl0c), [Single GPU Passthrough in Ubuntu AMD CPU/GPU](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eTX10QlFJ6c),   [GeForce PCIe Passthrough Enabled! But what took so long???](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12JtV1ou6EQ).